# How to detect ad blocker in my android app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob, adblock

Is there any way to detect when ad blocker is running in app ? I want to detect in my app that if user uses any app to block ads in app. if yes then I want to show popup to user to ask him to disable ad blocker while using app.

Comment: Seems like people here just doing downvoting games even without reading issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official method provided by the Android operating system to programmatically detect whether an ad blocker is installed on a device. Android does not expose specific APIs or system-level information that can be used to determine the presence of ad-blocking software.

However, it's important to note that ad-blocking apps can work in various ways, such as modifying DNS settings, intercepting network traffic, or utilizing VPN services. In some cases, you may be able to infer the presence of an ad blocker indirectly by examining network requests and responses, but this approach may not be foolproof and can be challenging to implement reliably.

Please keep in mind that the ad-blocking functionality and detection methods can change over time as new software versions and techniques are developed. It's a good practice to respect users' preferences and privacy choices regarding ad blockers.